# Saving a UIImage to the camera roll is only working on the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to save an image on the screen to the camera roll. The method that am using works absolutely perfectly in the simulator, but the image is 100% white on an actual device and I have no idea why. Heres the code.

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let snapShot:UIView = backgroundImage.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.bounds.size)

    snapShot.drawViewHierarchyInRect(backgroundImage.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)


}
```

Again, the image is saved perfectly on the simulator but a real device receives a blank image.

**I found out what to do:**

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backgroundImage.bounds.size, true, 1.0)
    backgroundImage.drawViewHierarchyInRect(backgroundImage.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)


}
```

Comment: It should work on real device.
for simulator you can save image to gallery from browser by long press on image.

Comment: @PrabhatPankaj if it worked I wouldn't have asked the question. I figured it out on my own though.